# BSOD in USB-Wifi Driver - rtwlanu.sys - System Thread Exception not Handled

Tags: windows, usb, crash, bsod, wifi-driver

The driver is from an USB-Wifi. I've been getting a BSOD in Windows 8 saying "System Thread Exception not Handled". So i've read this http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/solved-how-to-stop-encountering-a-blue-screen/88fd5b49-e28e-4643-8805-04df8bd85775 however, when i removed the drivers, rebooted and plugged in the USB, it BSOD again. So, i've downloaded Drivers from their official site and replaced them, still i get the BSOD.

How could i fix this?

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1213415/bsod-error-on-new-system

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to my mind:

- The drivers aren't compatible with windows 8
- The card is broken

Comment: If you look at the link i've posted, it's on Windows 8. Still, don't know why i get BSOD.

Comment: Does the card work in another OS?

Comment: Seems like it works on Windows 7. Seems like i'm going to downgrade that PC to Windows 7. (Using Windows 8)