# BSOD error on new system

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

My computer was running super fine up and until recently when it started giving me random BSOD errors. I am running windows 10 home 64bit with NO overclocking.

I have updated all the drivers to latest version and there are no virus or malware in my machine. I ran the "sfc /scannow" command in CP and it tells me that everything is fine and dandy.

I received some BSOD in the past, not frequent, due to the Wdiwifi.sys. [Bad Pool memory] on my other system. I went to device manager and checked for updates and everything is up-to-date.

The other two ndis.sys BSOD [kernel security check failure] error was caused when I was using blender. It was random.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0z47lWdEdGPZlVtY1lmTGh4Wms/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: share the dmp files so that we can try to debug them. Blurscreenview is crap

Comment: @magicandre1981 how do I share the file? you can grab the file from here https://www.tenforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/85464-random-bsod-while-rendering-related-netowrk-driver.html#post1034889

Comment: upload them to onedrive and create a share link and paste the link here

Comment: @magicandre1981 Done.

Comment: MS hasn't uploaded the PDBs for latest update rollup. I need to check this in a few days.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Okay. Please do.

Comment: the PDBs are now online and I posted what I saw from the dump

Comment: have you tried other Realtek Wifi drivers?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I installed a new windows on that same day, and this time I didn't install any LAN driver from the site of the motherboard. So far no BSOD(touchwood). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug symbols are now online.

[Analyzing the dumps with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows that the Realtek Wifi driver (`rtwlanu.sys`) causes the issue:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE (139)
A kernel component has corrupted a critical data structure.  The corruption
could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this machine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A LIST_ENTRY has been corrupted (i.e. double remove).
Arg2: ffff80016eb9a480, Address of the trap frame for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffff80016eb9a3d8, Address of the exception record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, Reserved

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffff80016eb9a3d8 -- (.exr 0xffff80016eb9a3d8)
ExceptionAddress: fffff809b0985c1b (ndis!ndisFreeNblToNPagedPool+0x000000000000006b)
   ExceptionCode: c0000409 (Security check failure or stack buffer overrun)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000003
Subcode: 0x3 FAST_FAIL_CORRUPT_LIST_ENTRY

STACK_TEXT:
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiFastFailDispatch
03 nt!KiRaiseSecurityCheckFailure
04 ndis!ndisFreeNblToNPagedPool
05 ndis!NdisFreeNetBufferList
06 rtwlanu!WDI_FreeRxFrame
07 rtwlanu!N6UsbWdi_RxReturnFrames
08 wdiwifi!CRxMgr::OnNdisReturnNetBufferLists
09 wdiwifi!CAdapter::ReturnNetBufferLists
0a wdiwifi!CPort::IndicateFrames
0b wdiwifi!CRxMgr::RxIndicatePortFrames
0c wdiwifi!CRxMgr::RxProcessAndIndicateNblChain
0d wdiwifi!CRxMgr::RxInOrderDataInd
0e wdiwifi!AdapterRxInorderDataInd
0f rtwlanu!wdi_NotifyPeerData
10 rtwlanu!WDI_NotifyDataInQueue
11 rtwlanu!RxNotifyThreadCallback
12 rtwlanu!Ndis6ThreadCallback
13 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
14 nt!KiStartSystemThread

    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\rtwlanu.sys
    Image name: rtwlanu.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Tue Nov 15 17:34:02 2016
```

Because I see the callstack for the realtek driver, I see that you use the buildin driver of Windows. Get and install the [latest driver from Realtek website](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/).

Comment: Actually I installed windows 10, then installed the LAN driver from the bundle I downloaded from the mobo's manufacturer, then I plugged in my Wifi NANO USB.