# can someone analyze this minidump for me

Tags: windows, windows-7, bsod, minidumps

i need someone to analyze this minidump with windbg ,because i don't the windows driver kit, plus i've been getting alot of bsods with the same error code in random times, also its a fresh and new system

here is the link to the minidump

https://www.mediafire.com/file/zeukp6g2pczel86/081621-26640-01.dmp/file

Comment: bluescreenview is crap it didnt show more details and info

Comment: @ØMλŘ - If you were to use WinDBG to analyze the problem it would pinpoint the issue, or at least provide us, the required log file to debug the problem.

Comment: no it will provide us the cause of it and where its path ,look at magicandre1981 how he have done it : https://superuser.com/questions/1213415/bsod-error-on-new-system